# Hydrocarbons with only 4 carbon atoms

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula, isomers

How many different organic structures (from the pure theoretical viewpoint) can be drawed with only 4 (exact) carbon atoms and with/without hydrogen? Polycyclic compounds and bridged compounds are also allowed. **Please, name them all as well!** :)

Remark: I have drawed the chemical graphs in a piece of paper (the skeletons) and I get 37 graphs (including linear with simple, double and triple bonds, and planar and nonplanar compounds), without geometric isomerism (cis/trans). Is that OK?

Comment: I top out at 23. I'd be curious to see your list.

Comment: Are you including non-existent compounds like cyclo-C4, cyclobutadiyne, for example?

Comment: exactly 4 carbons, or 1 to 4 carbons?  Does this include ions? Radicals?

Comment: Exact 4 carbons, including non-existent (non "made" compounds, i.e., theoretical, as I stated)...I got 36...Like my current age, and I want to know if I am right...

Comment: I think pentavalent carbon is more realistic than some of those: http://www.scs.illinois.edu/denmark/presentations/2007/gm-2007-04-17.pdf

Comment: There is also cis/trans 2-butene in real world. In theoretical world you could draw cis/trans isomers for some cyclobutenes too

Comment: @DavePhD  Dave, how would pentavalent carbon play into this when there are only 4 carbons?

Comment: @Ron Because carbon can bond hydrogens, not just other carbons.

Comment: What about the same question with 5 carbons? I guess the number of chemical graphs become larger...

Comment: https://oeis.org/A134818 Here's the latest list, stereoisomers ignored.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Final update, all earlier edits incorporated.

**Groundrules**: Considering compounds with:

- only carbon and hydrogen
- only 4 bonds to carbon

There are **37** isomers without considering *trans* isomers; **49** when *trans* isomers are included.  Also, many of these compounds seem extremely unstable and therefore unlikely to exist.

**Note to self**: check back in 20 years and see how many of the unlikely ones have been detected.

[image]

Names by row:

- butane, isobutane
- but-1-ene, but-2-ene, 2-methylpropene
- buta-1,3-diene, buta-1,2-diene, buta-1,2,3-triene
- but-1-yne, but-2-yne, but-1-ene-3-yne, buta-1,3-diyne
- methylcyclopropane, 2-methylcyclopropene, 1-methylcyclopropene, methylenecyclopropane, methylenecyclopropene, methlycyclopropadiene
- methylcyclopropyne, methlenecyclopropyne
- cyclobutane, cyclobutene, cyclobuta-1,2-diene, cyclobuta-1,3-diene, cyclobutatriene, cyclobutatetraene, cyclobutyne, cyclobutenyne, cyclobutadiyne
- bicyclobutane, bicyclobut-1(3)-ene, bicyclobut-1(2)-ene, bicyclobuta-1,3-diene, bicyclobuta-1,2-diene
- tetrahedrane, tetrahedrene, tetrahedradiene

Comment: Comparing with my skeletons, you lack a 1methyl-cyclopropene, and the cyclobutatriene with 3 double bonds (irrespectively it existed or not, you have not drawed it). Also, you have not drawed the C4 (the square with 4 double bonds). Thus, I get 36 (or 37, if I include the cis/trans versions of 2-butene, that I had not considered diferent so far).

Comment: @ron You might want to include a note for posterity that some of these "compounds" are incredibly strained and likely unstable. (This was why I was including ?? marks in my answer.)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison  A couple of things 1) I'd suggest leaving your answer in place, it is nice work, 2) regarding 1,3- butadiene are you talking about s-cis and s-trans about the 2-3 bond?

Comment: @GeoffHutchison There is a higher than normal barrier to rotation about the 2,3-bond in 1,3-butadiene due to a contribution from the resonance structure with a 2-3 double bond. However, the barrier is still low enough that the s-cis and s-trans forms are generally considered rotamers.

Comment: Now I get 37 (without cis-trans): you are left a bicyclo[1.1.0]but-1,1-diene, I think...Indeed, I also forgot it in my first skeletons!

Comment: cyclobuta-1,2-diene could have enantomers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allene

Comment: Is it legitimate to refer to cyclobutatetraene and cyclobutadiyne as different compounds, or are they just different resonance structures?  Both are just a ring of 4 carbon atoms and no hydrogen.

Comment: @DavePhD I pictured cyclobutadiyne as having 2 sets of non-equivalent bonds, whereas the bond lengths in cyclobutatetraene were all equivalent.  So they're not resonance structures, but probably not much of a barrier separating them.

Comment: @ron like Fig. 3 of http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja0123002

Comment: @DavePhD I can't get to fig. 3, but do you understand my argument about the 2 molecules having different bond lengths, therefore they can't be resonance structures?

Comment: @ron, yes I understand what you are saying, that cyclic C4 with all bond lengths equal would be one compound and C4 with alternating short and long would be a different compound (but Fig. 3 of article refers to these as resonance structures in another cyclic pure-carbon compound).  Another article makes calculations for linear C4 and cyclic C4 and says the calculated electronic structure of cyclic C4 is alternating short and long bonds.  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000926149500801A#

Comment: @DavePhD  Do they say how much higher in energy the cumulenic isomer is and what barrier separates the 2 isomers?

Comment: @ron, actually after looking at a 3rd article http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00081a041, it looks like C4 has two possible isomers: a linear isomer with bond lengths 1.32, 1.30, 1.32; and a rhombic (cyclic or bicyclic) isomer with 4 bond lengths of 1.46 and two 63 degree angles and two larger angles, with the linear isomer being lower energy.

Comment: @ron Shouldn't 4th molecule from the left on the 5th row be named methylidenecyclopropane?

Comment: @Mockingbird  I don't think so.  If you google "methylidenecyclopropane" all you get back is "methylenecyclopropane".  "Methylenecyclopropane" is also the name used by Wikipedia.

Comment: @ron So why "methlenecyclopropyne" when "methylenecylclopropane"?

Comment: "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Methylenecyclopropane" says methylidenecyclopropane also works.

Comment: **Cyclobutatetraene??** Are you kidding me?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal It fits within the stated "ground rules".

Answer (score 12):

> How many different organic structures (from the pure theoretical
>   viewpoint) can be drawed with only 4 (exact) carbon atoms and
>   with/without hydrogen?

We could make strict rules like each carbon has exactly 4 bonds and get a specific answer, but this is not reality.  There can be lone pair electrons and unpaired electrons.  The octet rule is not stictly followed.

$\ce {C_4}$ actually has been observed and is linear.

:C=C=C=C:

$\ce {C_4}$ has been the subject of numerous theoretical and experimetal papers because of its possible occurrence in nebulae. It has been debated whether a singlet linear, triplet linear or rhombic (kite shape) state is the lowest energy state.  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0009261400005765

Neither the linear nor rhombic states follow the naive rules.

Linear $\ce{C_4H}$ has been observed both in the lab and outer space.

In fact according to the University of Kohn lists [Molecules in Space](http://www.astro.uni-koeln.de/cdms/molecules), linear $\ce{C_4H}$ is one of only 61 molecules and molecular ions found in extragalactic space and of only 190 found in the interstellar medium or circumstellar shells as of 2016.

For $\ce{C_4H_2}$ linear [butadiyne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacetylene) in known.  Cyclobutatriene, cyclobutenyne and tetrahedrene have been ruled out theoretically as not represtenting any actual potential energy local minimum, while similar to $\ce {C_4}$, structures having lone pair or unpaired electrons and not following the octet rule (such as [carbenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbene)) have been calculated to represent actual minima.  See the following references for theoretical cyclic $\ce{C_4H_2}$ structures:

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcc.540020211/pdf

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo060698k

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo000941u

In outer space, not only has the usual HCCCCH isomer been found but also $\ce{H2CCCC}$

See [Observations of cumulene carbenes, H2CCCC and H2CCC, in TMC-1](http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/abs/1991PASJ...43..607K)

Comment: Yes, I was wondering as well how many of these structures are in fact known from the experimental side...