# Number of cyclic isomers of C4H6

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

I faced a question

> How many cyclic isomers are possible for $\ce{C4H6}$?

I and my friend found the following four.
[image]

But the answer key says there are 5. So what's the other one?

Comment: Your formula and the figures you've drawn don't match, the formula contains $3$ carbons and each of your figures has $4$ carbons.

Comment: We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field due to issues it gives rise to; see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: There's also bicyclobutane.

Comment: I find it easier to deal with such questions using the Degrees of Unsaturation...

Comment: The main difficulty with this question is deciding whether or not to include trans-cyclobutene.

Comment: @EashaanGodbole Link (where I can learn this stuff extensively) please?

Comment: @Mockingbird You'll find it easily enough on the internet. Check YouTube too.

Comment: @DavePhD Why not trans-cyclopropenes if you wanna talk about hypothetical stuff.

Comment: @Mithoron ron lists them too here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19475/hydrocarbons-with-only-4-carbon-atoms.  I'm interested if there is a corresponding theoretical potential energy minimum for any of  them (trans-cyclopropenes or cyclobutenes).  Maybe I should ask a question about that.

Comment: @DavePhD Well, he listed _everything_

Comment: @Mithoron This question can be useful to the forum if I just change the title with " How to determine molecular/geometric structure from a chemical formula. Mersentery's answer is the one a student will look for.

Comment: jee 2008 right .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can answer such questions using D.U. (Degree of unsaturation)

The formula is $\mathrm{C + 1 - }\frac{H + X - N}{2}$

```
C = Carbon.
H = Hydrogen.
X = Halogen.
N = Nitrogen.
```

**If you get D.U. to be one, then in the structure there could be:**

- 1 double bond.
- 1 ring.

Let's take an example of $\ce{C4H8}$ which has D.U. equal to one.

- It can have three structures of **1 double bond**:

[image]

- It can have two structures of **1 ring**:

[image]

**Now for D.U. equal to two, the possibilities are:**

- 2 double bond.
- 2 ring.
- 1 double bond and 1 ring.
- 1 triple bond.

Let's take your example of $\ce{C4H6}$ which has D.U. equal to two:

- It can have two structures of **2 double bond**:

[image]

- It can have one structure of **2 ring**:

[image]

- It can have four structures of **1 double bond + 1 ring**:

[image]

- It can have two structures of **1 triple bond**:

[image]

So, the answer is 5 cyclic isomers as you can see above.

Comment: How do you decide whether or not the cyclobutene has both cis and trans isomers?

Comment: @DavePhD It cannot show geometrical isomerism as far as I can see.

Comment: "Now for D.U. equal to two, the possibilities are:

    2 double bond.

    2 ring.

    1 double bond and 1 ring.

    1 triple bond." how do u know that?

Comment: Drawing _angled_ $sp$ carbons is a sin bordering on blasphemy.

Comment: @Mesentery Hypothetically, with respect to the double bond, the two hydrogens  could be on one side and the two carbons on the other (cis) or there could be one hydrogen on each side with the ring stretching diagonally across the double bond.  But I don't think it is known to occur experimentally for a ring this small http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/vlu_organik/stereochemie/cyclische_stereoisomere.vlu/Page/vsc/en/ch/2/oc/stoffklassen/systematik_struktur/cyclische_verbindungen/carbocyclisch/cycloalkene/physikalische_eigenschaften.vscml.html

Comment: @Mockingbird That I have studied. But you can also make out like D.U. Is 2 means there should be 2 double bonds that are removing the hydrogen from the formula. And it can have 2 rings that all that. You will have two check what are the possibilities that can remove hydrogen from an alkane

Comment: @DavePhD Thanks for the information. I have studied that cyclic alkenes does not show geometrical isomerism having carbon less than 8.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Apologies for committing the sin :)

Comment: @Mesentery well perhaps you will find this article interesting, concerning the limit supposedly being 8 http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja055388i and also http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00389a067

Comment: Now that's much better. But look, a carbon with two double bonds is also an $sp$ carbon.

Comment: @IvanNeretin You are referring to the Allene. Ok Thanks.

Comment: @Mersentery Is the formula empirical?

Comment: @Mockingbird You can have an idea how the formula is made from [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Organic_Chemistry/Alkenes/Properties_of_Alkenes/Degree_of_Unsaturation). BTW I don't understand what you mean by empirical.