# Name of cyclic tetraatomic carbon molecule

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I came across this [article](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/172281/why-is-a-c4-ring-impossible) on stack exchange which mentioned a cyclic compound of four carbon atoms each connected with a double bond to the two adjacent carbon atoms. However, this made me think what would be the name given to such a compound. Also, could this similar compound exist? If so, what would be its name?

[image: compound]

Comment: This abomination ist called C4, and it is very unstable. Joking aside though, his is just one possible structure of $\ce{C4}$, and they all are unstable. The image given here likely is not a good approximation to what a "quadratic" arrangement of 4 carbons would be like.

Comment: One could call such structure cyclobutadiyne. Except it's organic nomenclature name.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19475/hydrocarbons-with-only-4-carbon-atoms